# Linker command failed with exit code 1 C++

Tags: c++, xcode

### My project setting is

- Xcode 8.3 (8E162)
- Language C++

### My project structure is

```
├── README.md
├── TrollLanguage
│   ├── TokenParser.cpp
│   ├── TokenParser.hpp
│   └── main.cpp
```

### My source code is

#### main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "TokenParser.hpp"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    // insert code here...
    std::cout << "Hello, World!\n";
    TokenParser *tokenParser = new TokenParser();
    tokenParser->TestFunc();
    return 0;
}
```

#### TokenParser.cpp

```
#include "TokenParser.hpp"

void TestFunc() {
    std::cout << "can u see me?";
}
enter code here
```

#### TokenParser.hpp

```
#ifndef TokenParser_hpp
#define TokenParser_hpp

#include <iostream>

class TokenParser {
public:
    void TestFunc();
};

#endif /* TokenParser_hpp */
```

### Expected behavior is

```
Hello, World!
can u see me?
```

### Actual behavior is

```
Apple Mach-O Linker (Id) Error
"TokenParser::TestFunc()", referenced from:
Linker command failed with exit code 1(use -v to see invocation
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to prepend the class name as part of the function definition in the implementation file. As it stands, you're defining a free function called `TestFunc`.

```
#include "TokenParser.hpp"

void TokenParser::TestFunc() {
    std::cout << "can u see me?";
}
```

Comment: It build success, but can't see (can u see me?)

Comment: strange. Either add `std::cout << std::endl` or a call to `std::cout.flush()` somewhere before returning from the `main` function

Comment: If your trouble is resolved, please accept the answer

Comment: stack overflow says, wait 2 min. sorry.